# Date Parse triggers error in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to parse a date string in `mm/dd/yyyy` to date type, but it triggers an error saying:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Dim mydate As Date
If filter = 4 Then
    mydate = Date.ParseExact(datepart, "mm/dd/yy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
End If
```

I don't understand what I did wrong, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the content of `datepart`.

Comment: What's the value of `datepart` when it throws this exception?

Comment: I think the format should be "mm/dd/yyyy". Make sure the datepart variable has the format provided.

Comment: And if your date is in the `MM/DD/YYYY` format, why are you telling it to parse in exactly the `MM/DD/YY` format?

Comment: @RenéVogt Sorry.. I missed that in question. Please check the modification

Comment: @TZHX I missed that in question. Please check the modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format is wrong, use `MM/dd/yyyy` instead `mm/dd/yy` try below

```
Date.ParseExact(datepart, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the reason. I tried and again it shows the same error when trying to parse

Answer (score 2):

You have two little errors in your format string:

```
DateTime mydate = DateTime.ParseExact("07/27/2016",
                                      "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                      System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

1. Months are parsed by `"MM"` not `"mm"` (lower case is for minutes)
2. The **four** digit year is parsed by `"yyyy"` not `"yy"`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Thats exactly the bug!

Answer (score 0):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

// Parse date-only value with invariant culture.
string dateString = "06/15/2008";
string format = "d";

var result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```